# Fortran is reading beyond endfile record

Tags: fortran, gfortran, eof, data-files

I'm trying to read some data from a file, and the endfile record detection is important to stop reading. However, depending of the array dimensions of the array used to read data, I cannot detect properly the endfile record and my Fortran program stops.

The program is below:

```
!integer, dimension(3) :: x                      ! line 1.1
!integer, dimension(3,10) :: x                   ! line 1.2
integer, dimension(10,3) ::                      ! line 1.3
integer :: status,i=1
character(len=100) :: error

open( 30, file='data.dat', status='old' )
do
  print *,i
  !read( 30, *, iostat=status, iomsg=error ) x          ! line 2.1
  !read( 30, *, iostat=status, iomsg=error ) x(:,i)     ! line 2.2
  read( 30, *, iostat=status, iomsg=error ) x(i,:)      ! line 2.3

  if ( status < 0 ) then        print *,'EOF'
    print *,'total of ',i-1,' lines read.'
    exit
  else if ( status > 0 ) then
    print *,'error cod: ',status
    print *,'error message: ', error
    stop
  else if ( status == 0 ) then
    print *,'reading ok.'
    i = i + 1
  end if
end do
```

With 'data.dat' file been:

```
10 20 30
30 40 50
```

When lines 1.3 and 2.3 are uncommented the mentioned error appears:

> error cod: 5008
>
> error message: Read past ENDFILE record

However, using lines 1.1 and 2.1, or 1.2 and 2.2, the program works, detecting endfile record.

So, I would like some help on understanding why I cannot use lines 1.3 and 2.3 to read properly this file, since I'm giving the correct number of array elements for read command.

I'm using gfortran compiler, version 6.3.0.

EDIT: simpler example

the following produces a 5008 "Read past ENDFILE record" error:

```
implicit none
integer x(2,2),s
open(20,file='noexist')
read(20,*,iostat=s)x
write(*,*)s
end
```

if we make `x` a scalar or a one-d array ( any size ) we get the expected `-1` EOF flag. It doesn't matter if the file actually doesn't exist or is empty.  If the file contains *some*, but not enough, data its hard to make sense of which return value you might get.

Comment: Please show output from when you run this program (working and non-working variants).  It isn't clear to me why you would get a message about an end-of-file condition so the exact output will clarify.

Comment: You don't have an 'x' in line 1.3. Is this just a transcribing error?

Comment: Interesting. I'm able to replicate the issue with gfortran 4.8 but not ifort 16.0. I agree it's a problem.

Comment: gfortran 7.2 has the same problem.

Comment: confirmed, (gfortran 4.8.5). I edited the question to show the actual message I get.   this is clearly a gfortran bug. You can workaround simply by making your first test `status < 0 .or. status == 5008`

Comment: After a bit of investigating , gfortran seems to only throw an actual EOF (status=-1) when attempting to read a single scalar item. The "past end" error is thrown when it hits EOF while reading an array.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I am expressing myself correctly but it has to do with the way fortran is reading and storing 2d-arrays. When you are using this notation: `x(:,i)`, the column `i` is virtually expanded in-line and the items are read using this one line of code. In the other case where `x(i,:)` is used, the row `i` is read as if you called `read` multiple times.
You may use implied loops if you want to stick with a specific shape and size. For example you could use something like that:`read( 30, *, iostat=status, iomsg=error ) (x(i,j), j=1,3)`

In any case you should check that your data are stored properly (as expected at least) in variable `x`.

Comment: Why do you expect `(x(i,j),j=1,3)` to be different from `x(i,1:3)`?  And why is using `x(i,:)` like using multiple read statements?

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: @francescalus I agree that it should not be different, but  it has happened to me before. Some compilers exhibited the behaviour I described.

Answer (score -1):

Please note this is only a guess. Remember that Fortran stores arrays in column major order. When gfortran compiles `read() x(:,i)`, the 3 memory locations are next to each other so in the executable, it produces a single call to the operating system to read in 3 values from the file.

Now when `read() x(i,:)` is compiled, the three data elements `x(i,1)`, `x(i,2)` and `x(i,3)` are not in contiguous memory. So I am guessing the executable actually has 3 read calls to the operating system. The first one would trap the EOF but the 2nd one gives you the read past end of file error.

UPDATE: I have confirmed that this does not occur with Intel's ifort. gfortran seems to have had a similar problem before: [Bad IOSTAT values when readings NAMELISTs past EOF](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=31052). Whether this is a bug or not is debatable. The code certainly looks like it should trap an EOF.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: Namelist input is quite different from ordinary file input.